# Push data into a complex JSON object

Tags: arrays, json

I want to create an json object which final structure should look something like this:

```
crossdata = {
     "reports" : {
                   {"name" : "emp1", "age" : "20", "height" : "180"},
                   {"name" : "emp2", "age" : "33", "height" : "185"},
                   {"name" : "emp3", "age" : "31", "height" : "176"}
                   {"name" : "emp4", "age" : "42", "height" : "188"}
                 },
     "process" : {
                   {"time" : "260", "opt" : "1", "area" : "north", "active" : "1"},
                   {"time" : "123", "opt" : "0", "area" : "north", "active" : "1"},
                 },
     "status" : {
                   {"actual" : "1", "sync" : "1"},
                   {"actual" : "1", "sync" : "0"},
                   {"actual" : "0", "sync" : "0"},
                 }
        }
```

As you can see, the three objects (or are they arrays?) inside crossdata may have different number of "records", with data collected from IndexedDB.

So, at the top line I declared:

```
crossdata = { "reports" : {}, "process" : {}, "status" : {} };
```

And then I tried to push the data gathered from the DB inside recurring loops:

```
      //some DB code (reports table) // (function(r){
        for (i=0; i<r.length; i++){
          crossdata.reports.push ({
            "name" : r[i].name, "age" : r[i].age, "height" : r[i].height
          });
        }
      });
      //some DB code (process table) // (function(r){
        for (i=0; i<r.length; i++){
          crossdata.process.push ({
            "time" : r[i].time, "opt" : r[i].opt, "area" : r[i].area, "active" : r[i].active
          });
        }
      });
      //some DB code (status table) // (function(r){
        for (i=0; i<r.length; i++){
          crossdata.status.push ({
            "actual" : r[i].actual, "sync" : r[i].sync
          });
        }
      });
```

But, it doesn't work, I keep receiving an error indicating that `crossdata.reports.push` is not a function. I guess it has something to do with arrays vs. objects, square brackets and parsing, but applying solutions from similar discussions didn't work for me.

Any idea about how to achieve this kind of a structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
crossdata = { "reports" : [], "process" : [], "status" : [] };
```

to declare arrays. You declared objects there, which do not have a native `push()` method.

`{}` is an object literal, while `[]` is an array literal. If you want to use array functions like `push()` you obviously have to declare arrays.